# Restricting rights on GitHub

Tags: git, github, pull-request

My team is currently using Gerrit as code review tool for our git repos. Now we want to move some of them to GitHub. I'm not expecting to have as fine grained control over the rights as would be the case with Gerrit.

I would however like to restrict direct pushing onto master. People should first create a pull request and then have this merged by a colleague. These same people should be able to merge pull requests, so not giving them any rights on the repo is not an option.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: A pull request happens between repos, not between branches, right? So you want people to be able to merge PRs in `master`, but not push directly?

Comment: You should educate people to simply not directly push anything to master but to always go through merge requests. Even GitHub itself does that for themselves too.

Comment: @CharlesB: Pull requests can occur from any other branch, thus from both forks and the original repo. I indeed want to prevent direct pushes, as those would bypass review.

Comment: A merge onto master will always end up with a *direct* push, so even if you could restrict access on a branch level on GitHub, this would still not work. Access managers like Gitolite offer this kind of access restrictions but GitHub is meant to be simple.

Comment: also see https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-the-different-access-permissions, permissions to merge PR are given to the push team, so there's no way to allow PR and deny push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github doesn't have fine-grain permission settings, or at least not fine enough to disallow push but allow merging pull-request. Pre-receive hooks would also allow to distinguish pushes and pull-requests, but they can't be used on GitHub. So you have two options:

- forbid people from directly pushing to GitHub, even if technically they can
- use GitLab along with Gitolite, which will allow much more powerful permissions, and provide the same kind of functionalities than GitHub